# Are there any peer-reviewed papers on the maximum waiting time to be considered "user real-time"?

Tags: response-time, hci, real-time-updates, user-perception

Are there any scientific papers about any study performed on what is considered a maximum waiting time for an activity to be considered "user real-time" (not software real-time).

I was looking at something along the lines of "maximum waiting time for a web page to render" and the user's perception of real-time.

For instance empirically, we can state that waiting 200 ms would be real-time whereas waiting 10 seconds would not, but I was hoping to find some citation for it in scientific literature.

I've tried some resources (eg Google Scholar) but to no avail.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi FrankZappa, welcome to UX.se! This has been answered multiple times here. http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-is-an-acceptable-response-time-for-my-ajax-ui http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30770/studies-showing-the-impact-of-response-time-variability-on-user-experience All quoting http://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chapter 3 of [Designing and Engineering Time by S.Seow](http://www.engineeringtime.com/) there are list of standards which consern time and user experience. In average, "user real-time" response is in interval of 0.2-1.0 sec.