# In which position does a loading spinner look faster?

Tags: speed, spinner, user-perception

I know that if a spinner spins backwards or faster or both the whole loading will be perceived as faster by the user. But what about its position near a text? Let me make an example...

Loading item... [image]

vs

[image] Loading item...

Better left or right? which ones make the process seem faster?

Should also the text animate somehow to strengthen this perception?

Comment: Is the item going to be text or image? I think you should worry more about streamlining the "jump" between loading animation and ready appearance than what position is perceived to be 2 microseconds shorter

Comment: @Navot It is text.

Comment: Then have the spinner to the right, so text will align with text

Comment: A spinner moving faster will give the perception that the page is loading faster?  What in the world???

Comment: @JonH http://uxmovement.com/buttons/how-to-make-progress-bars-feel-faster-to-users/ http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18361/why-do-progress-bars-animate-backwards and http://www.chrisharrison.net/projects/progressbars2/ProgressBarsHarrison.pdf specifically the "pulsation" thing.

Comment: @Navot I finally opted to move the spinner.

Comment: This is simply cool...I had no idea there were studies done on this.

Comment: @JonH Indeed. that's why I asked :-)

Comment: Fair enough, its rather strange and yet interesting at the same time.  I did notice it on google's gmail service so apparently this isn't anything new...its been studied and tested.  Humans are just odd beings I guess...we see a spinning loader and because its faster we assume a page loads faster - brilliant!

Comment: I say fortunately we can be exploited like this. That's until we find a way to make code faster in a cheaper way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to dislike 'animated' text, it does disrupt readability. I don't think increasing the speed of the animation will help, if you have a very long load time, you might want to approach the problem differently such as providing some 'filler' content within the loading screen.

Have you considered using verticality for placement of text and animation?

[image: Such as this:]

Comment: I'm *still* waiting for this image to load...how big *is* it?

Comment: It's not big at all:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/tnAnA.gif (direct link)

Comment: 37 kb. If that's too large, an upgrade of internet provider might be something to consider :)

Comment: As for the loading time it differs often, not always the same. but placing text below spinner is not an option as I should also center the whole element thereafter

Comment: Ideally gif spinner should fit on <3 network packets but for me it loaded just fine.